Getting too many TooManyConnectionsError from asyncpg exceptions after couple of success test cases
I am trying to run my test suite using pytest library. I am using @pytest.mark.asyncio and @pytest.mark.parametrize approach to cover multiple scenarios in a test function.
As far as my code flow is concerned. I have a main

conftest.py

class TestConnectionManager(ConnectionManager):
    def __init__(self, test_db_url):
        self._test_db_url = test_db_url
        super().__init__()  # Call the parent class's constructor

    def _setup_db(self):
        async_db_url = self._test_db_url.replace(
            "postgresql+psycopg2://", "postgresql+asyncpg://"
        )

        engine = create_async_engine(
            async_db_url,
            echo=loaded_config.DB_ECHO,
            pool_size=50,  # Increase pool size
            max_overflow=10,  # Increase overflow size
            pool_timeout=60,  # Increase timeout duration
            # pool_recycle=3600  # Recycle connections after an hour
        )
        session_factory = async_scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(
                engine,
                expire_on_commit=False,
                class_=AsyncSession,
            ),
            scopefunc=current_task,
        )
        return engine, session_factory


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_db_connection_manager(test_db_url):
    connection_manager = TestConnectionManager(test_db_url)
    yield connection_manager
    # Clean up
    import asyncio  # noqa: 41

    # TODO: Find a more elegant way to teardown session connections
    # asyncio.run(connection_manager.close_connections())

here is my

otb/conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(
    params=[(fake.unique.bothify(text="R###"), fake.company()) for _ in range(3)],
    ids=[
        "Brand Parameter 1",
        "Brand Parameter 2",
        "Brand Parameter 3",
    ],
    scope="module",
)
def brand_params(request):
    return request.param


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def brand_uuid(test_session_factory, brand_params):
    session = test_session_factory()

    brand_code, brand_name = brand_params
    brand = Brand(id=uuid.uuid4(), code=brand_code, brand=brand_name)
    session.add(brand)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(brand)
    return brand.id


@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        (
            f"{fake.random_number(digits=2, fix_len=True):02d}",
            f"Division " f"{fake.random_number(digits=2, fix_len=True):02d}",
        )
        for _ in range(3)
    ],
    ids=[
        "Division Parameter 1",
        "Division Parameter 2",
        "Division Parameter 3",
    ],
    scope="module",
)
def division_params(request):
    return request.param


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def division_uuid(test_session_factory, division_params):
    session = test_session_factory()

    division_code, division_name = division_params
    division = Division(id=uuid.uuid4(), code=division_code, division=division_name)
    session.add(division)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(division)
    return division.id

and here is

test_dao.py

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def otb_number(
    brand_uuid,
    division_uuid,
    fashion_grade_uuid,
    season_uuid,
    purchase_group_uuid,
    format_master_uuid,
    test_session_factory,
):
    session = test_session_factory()

    brand = await session.get(Brand, brand_uuid)
    division = await session.get(Division, division_uuid)
    fashion_grade = await session.get(Fashion_grade, fashion_grade_uuid)
    season = await session.get(Season, season_uuid)
    purchase_group = await session.get(PurchaseGroup, purchase_group_uuid)
    format_master = await session.get(FormatMaster, format_master_uuid)

    season_year = random.randint(1000, datetime.now().year)

    otb_number = (
        f"{brand.code[:4]}{division.code[:2]}{fashion_grade.code[:4]}"
        f"{season.code[:4]}{season_year:04d}{format_master.format_code[:2]}{purchase_group.name[:3]}"
    )

    print("I AM OTB NUMBER", otb_number)

    await session.close()

    return otb_number

when for 2 Brand Parameters and 1 Division Parameter if otb_number is used with any of my test case as a dependency it runs completely fine executing all the combinations with the params.
The problem arises when I try to run test suite with 3 Brand Parameters and 3 Division Parameters, I get initial successful test results but after a certain point my test cases start failing with error as follows:

params = ConnectionParameters(user='xxx', password='xxx',
database='test_db', ssl=<ssl.SSLContext object at
0x12c9b8c80...slmode=<SSLMode.prefer: 2>, direct_tls=False,
server_settings=None, target_session_attrs=<SessionAttribute.any:
'any'>) retry = True, addr = ('localhost', 5432), loop =
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False> config
= ConnectionConfiguration(command_timeout=None, statement_cache_size=100, max_cached_statement_lifetime=300,
max_cacheable_statement_size=15360), connection_class = <class
'asyncpg.connection.Connection'> record_class = <class
'asyncpg.Record'> params_input = ConnectionParameters(user='xxx',
password='xxx', database='test_db', ssl=<ssl.SSLContext object at
0x12c9b8c80...slmode=<SSLMode.prefer: 2>, direct_tls=False,
server_settings=None, target_session_attrs=<SessionAttribute.any:
'any'>)
async def __connect_addr( params, retry, addr, loop, config,
connection_class, record_class, params_input, ): connected =
_create_future(loop) proto_factory = lambda: protocol.Protocol( addr, connected, params, record_class, loop) if isinstance(addr, str): #
UNIX socket connector = loop.create_unix_connection(proto_factory,
addr) elif params.ssl and params.direct_tls: # if ssl and direct_tls
are given, skip STARTTLS and perform direct # SSL connection connector
= loop.create_connection( proto_factory, *addr, ssl=params.ssl ) elif params.ssl: connector = _create_ssl_connection( proto_factory, *addr,
loop=loop, ssl_context=params.ssl, ssl_is_advisory=params.sslmode ==
SSLMode.prefer) else: connector =
loop.create_connection(proto_factory, *addr) tr, pr = await connector
try: > await connected E asyncpg.exceptions.TooManyConnectionsError:
sorry, too many clients already
procuro-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py:876:
TooManyConnectionsError
__________________ test_update_otb_data[Brand Parameter 1-Division Parameter 3-Fashion Grade Parameter 1-Season Parameter 1-PG Parameter 1-Positive OTB ID-OTB Budget Amount below consumed PR amount]

I have tried increasing the pool_size and max_overflow arguments of create_async_engine but still the same error saying asyncpg.exceptions.TooManyConnectionsError: sorry, too many clients already.
I am expecting with increase number of Brand or Division or any parameters my Test Suite should be capable to handle the async connections without failing.
